# Magento Style Error?

Tags: magento, styles, categories

I have installed Magento several times now and each time I install it and put some (sub)-categories in it, it works fine! After I have checked it out at the front-end, it all seemed okay. After this I go back to the back-end and when I want to edit categories I get this:

[image: Magento categorie style error]

Therefor i have installed Magento 1.6.2 again. And I got the same result. There was a fix I found on the internet, but it doesn't work. I can't see or edit anything. So I decided to install a newer version 1.7.0 RC1. And guess what? I got the same problem again :(

All the other pages are working fine, but why is the style gone of the categories page? :S 
Does anyone have an answer for this error??

Comment: Look at the path of css files. Is it correct path to you theme?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission for `media and var` folder in your magento root folder.

Comment: Nope still didnt work...i have them on CHMOD 777. To be sure I CHMODDED it again with all sub-directories en files...but still the same style issue. Could it be something with the server??